# When transferring files using front USB speed drops to 0 bits/sec

Tags: windows-10, usb, drivers

Sorry in advance if this isn't edited properly, this is the first time I'm using this site.

When transferring files they regularly drop down to 0b/sec, ports are plugged into a USB3.0 Header.

Information About my PC is:

```
    Operating System
        Windows 10 Pro 64-bit
    CPU
        Intel Core i7 3770 @ 3.40GHz    34 °C
        Ivy Bridge 22nm Technology
    RAM
        16.0GB Dual-Channel DDR3 @ 823MHz (11-11-11-27)
    Motherboard
        ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC. P8Z77-V PRO (LGA1155) 25 °C
    Graphics
        VS248 (1920x1080@60Hz)
        HP x20LED (1600x900@60Hz)
        3071MB NVIDIA GeForce GTX 780 Ti (ASUStek Computer Inc) 25 °C
    Storage
        931GB Samsung SSD 860 EVO 1TB (SATA (SSD))  26 °C
        3726GB Seagate ST4000DM000-1F2168 (SATA )   32 °C
        931GB Seagate ST1000DM003-9YN162 (SATA )    27 °C
        232GB Seagate ST3250820AS (SATA )   34 °C
```

Top 4 of the tree information is below. I used USB Device Tree Viewer to get this information. According to Windows I am using the latest driver, but I am not getting USB3.0 speed out of the front USB ports.

Intel(R) USB 3.0 eXtensible Host Controller - 1.0 (Microsoft)

---USB Root Hub (USB 3.0)
|HS-[6-1] (Front of PC) Should be USB3

|HS-[6-2] (Front of PC) Should be USB3

```
    +++++++++++++++++ Device Information ++++++++++++++++++
Friendly Name            : Intel(R) USB 3.0 eXtensible Host Controller - 1.0 (Microsoft)
Device Description       : USB xHCI Compliant Host Controller
Device Path              : \\?\PCI#VEN_8086&DEV_1E31&SUBSYS_84CA1043&REV_04#3&11583659&0&A0#{3abf6f2d-71c4-462a-8a92-1e6861e6af27} (GUID_DEVINTERFACE_USB_HOST_CONTROLLER)
Kernel Name              : \Device\NTPNP_PCI0003
Device ID                : PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_1E31&SUBSYS_84CA1043&REV_04\3&11583659&0&A0
Vendor                   : Intel
Hardware IDs             : PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_1E31&SUBSYS_84CA1043&REV_04 PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_1E31&SUBSYS_84CA1043 PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_1E31&CC_0C0330 PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_1E31&CC_0C03
Driver KeyName           : {36fc9e60-c465-11cf-8056-444553540000}\0000 (GUID_DEVCLASS_USB)
Driver                   : \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\USBXHCI.SYS (Version: 10.0.19041.1741  Date: 2022-06-19)
Driver Inf               : C:\Windows\inf\usbxhci.inf
Legacy BusType           : PCIBus
Class                    : USB
Class GUID               : {36fc9e60-c465-11cf-8056-444553540000} (GUID_DEVCLASS_USB)
Service                  : USBXHCI
Enumerator               : PCI
Location Info            : PCI bus 0, device 20, function 0
Location IDs             : PCIROOT(0)#PCI(1400), ACPI(_SB_)#ACPI(PCI0)#ACPI(XHC_)
Container ID             : {00000000-0000-0000-ffff-ffffffffffff} (GUID_CONTAINERID_INTERNALLY_CONNECTED_DEVICE)
Manufacturer Info        : Generic USB xHCI Host Controller
Capabilities             : 0x00 (-)
Status                   : 0x0180200A (DN_DRIVER_LOADED, DN_STARTED, DN_DISABLEABLE, DN_NT_ENUMERATOR, DN_NT_DRIVER)
Problem Code             : 0
Address                  : 1310720 (0x140000)
HcDisableSelectiveSuspend: 0
EnableSelectiveSuspend   : 0
SelectiveSuspendEnabled  : 0
EnhancedPowerMgmtEnabled : 0
IdleInWorkingState       : 0
WakeFromSleepState       : 0
Power State              : D0 (supported: D0, D3, wake from D3)
 Child Device 1          : USB Root Hub (USB 3.0)
  Device Path            : \\?\USB#ROOT_HUB30#4&a3f7854&0&0#{f18a0e88-c30c-11d0-8815-00a0c906bed8} (GUID_DEVINTERFACE_USB_HUB)
  Kernel Name            : \Device\USBPDO-1
  Device ID              : USB\ROOT_HUB30\4&A3F7854&0&0
  Class                  : USB
  Driver KeyName         : {36fc9e60-c465-11cf-8056-444553540000}\0008 (GUID_DEVCLASS_USB)
  Service                : USBHUB3
  LocationPaths          : PCIROOT(0)#PCI(1400)#USBROOT(0)  ACPI(_SB_)#ACPI(PCI0)#ACPI(XHC_)#ACPI(RHUB)

        --------------- USB Hostcontroller Info0 --------------
PciVendorId              : 0x8086 (Intel)
PciDeviceId              : 0x1E31
PciRevision              : 0x04
NumberOfRootPorts        : 0x04 (4 Ports)
ControllerFlavor         : 0x00 (0 = USB_HcGeneric)
HcFeatureFlags           : 0x08
 Port Power Switching    : no
 Selective Suspend       : no
 Legacy BIOS             : no
 Time Sync API           : yes

Roothub Symbolic Link    : USB#ROOT_HUB30#4&a3f7854&0&0#{f18a0e88-c30c-11d0-8815-00a0c906bed8}

        ----------- USB Hostcontroller BusStatistics ----------
DeviceCount              : 0x01 (1)
CurrentSystemTime        : 0x01D8954717906F2B (2022-07-11 12:55:57)
CurrentUsbFrame          : 0x8D9EA0E (148498958)
BulkBytes                : 0x00 (0)
IsoBytes                 : 0x00 (0)
InterruptBytes           : 0x00 (0)
ControlDataBytes         : 0x00 (0)
PciInterruptCount        : 0x01 (1)
HardResetCount           : 0x00 (0)
WorkerSignalCount        : 0x00 (0)
CommonBufferBytes        : 0x00 (0)
WorkerIdleTimeMs         : 0x00 (0)
RootHubEnabled           : 0x01 (yes)
RootHubDevicePowerState  : 0x02 (D2)
Unused                   : 0x00 (0)
NameIndex                : 0x00 (0)


        ------ USB Hostcontroller Driver Version Params -------
DriverTrackingCode       : 0x04
USBDI_Version            : 0x600
USBUSER_Version          : 0x04
CheckedPortDriver        : 0x00
CheckedMiniportDriver    : 0x00
USB_Version              : 0x00

        ---------- USB Hostcontroller Bandwidth Info ----------
DeviceCount              : 0x00000000 (0)
TotalBusBandwidth        : 0x0006D600 (448000 bits/ms = 56 MB/s)
Total32secBandwidth      : 0x00DAC000 (14336000 bits/32ms = 56 MB/s)
AllocedBulkAndControl    : 0x002BC000 (2867200 bits/32ms = 11.200 MB/s = 20%)
AllocedIso               : 0x00000000 (0 bits/32ms)
AllocedInterrupt_1ms     : 0x00000000 (0 bits/32ms)
AllocedInterrupt_2ms     : 0x00000000 (0 bits/32ms)
AllocedInterrupt_4ms     : 0x00000000 (0 bits/32ms)
AllocedInterrupt_8ms     : 0x00000000 (0 bits/32ms)
AllocedInterrupt_16ms    : 0x00000000 (0 bits/32ms)
AllocedInterrupt_32ms    : 0x00000000 (0 bits/32ms)


        -------- USB Hostcontroller Power States Info ---------
SystemState              : S0    S1    S2    S3    S4    S5    
HcDevicePowerState       : D0    --    --    D3    D3    --    
HcDeviceWake             : D3    D3    D3    D3    D3    D3    
HcSystemWake             : S4    S4    S4    S4    S4    S4    
RhDevicePowerState       : --    D3    D3    D2    D2    --    
RhDeviceWake             : D2    D2    D2    D2    D2    D2    
RhSystemWake             : S4    S4    S4    S4    S4    S4    
LastSystemSleepState     : --    --    --    --    --    --    
CanWakeup                : no    no    no    yes   yes   no    
IsPowered                : no    no    no    yes   yes   no
```

```
  ========================= USB Root Hub =========================
Sum of Hubs and Devices  : 0
Sum of Endpoints         : 0

        +++++++++++++++++ Device Information ++++++++++++++++++
Device Description       : USB Root Hub (USB 3.0)
Device Path              : \\?\USB#ROOT_HUB30#4&a3f7854&0&0#{f18a0e88-c30c-11d0-8815-00a0c906bed8} (GUID_DEVINTERFACE_USB_HUB)
Kernel Name              : \Device\USBPDO-1
Device ID                : USB\ROOT_HUB30\4&A3F7854&0&0
Hardware IDs             : USB\ROOT_HUB30&VID8086&PID1E31&REV0004 USB\ROOT_HUB30&VID8086&PID1E31 USB\ROOT_HUB30
Driver KeyName           : {36fc9e60-c465-11cf-8056-444553540000}\0008 (GUID_DEVCLASS_USB)
Driver                   : \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\UsbHub3.sys (Version: 10.0.19041.1202  Date: 2021-10-06)
Driver Inf               : C:\Windows\inf\usbhub3.inf
Legacy BusType           : PNPBus
Class                    : USB
Class GUID               : {36fc9e60-c465-11cf-8056-444553540000} (GUID_DEVCLASS_USB)
Service                  : USBHUB3
Enumerator               : USB
Location Info            : -
Manufacturer Info        : (Standard USB HUBs)
Capabilities             : 0x80 (SurpriseRemovalOK)
Status                   : 0x0180200A (DN_DRIVER_LOADED, DN_STARTED, DN_DISABLEABLE, DN_NT_ENUMERATOR, DN_NT_DRIVER)
Problem Code             : 0
Address                  : 0
HcDisableSelectiveSuspend: 0
EnableSelectiveSuspend   : 0
SelectiveSuspendEnabled  : 0
EnhancedPowerMgmtEnabled : 0
IdleInWorkingState       : 1
WakeFromSleepState       : 0
Power State              : D2 (supported: D0, D2, D3, wake from D0, wake from D2)

        ------------------- USB Hub Descriptor -----------------
bDescriptorLength        : 0x09 (9 bytes)
bDescriptorType          : 0x29 (Hub Descriptor)
bNumberOfPorts           : 0x08 (8 Ports)
wHubCharacteristics      : 0x0000
 Power switching         : Ganged
 Compound device         : No
 Over-current protection : Global
 TT Think Time           : At most 8 FS bit times
 Port Indicators         : Not supported
bPowerOnToPowerGood      : 0x02 (4 ms)
bHubControlCurrent       : 0x00 (0 mA)
DeviceRemovable          : 0x00, 0x00
 Bit 0                   : 0 (reserved, any value)
 Bit 1                   : 0 (Device at Port 1 is removable)
 Bit 2                   : 0 (Device at Port 2 is removable)
 Bit 3                   : 0 (Device at Port 3 is removable)
 Bit 4                   : 0 (Device at Port 4 is removable)
 Bit 5                   : 0 (Device at Port 5 is removable)
 Bit 6                   : 0 (Device at Port 6 is removable)
 Bit 7                   : 0 (Device at Port 7 is removable)
 Bit 8                   : 0 (Device at Port 8 is removable)
 Bit 9                   : 0 (unused, must be 0)
 Bit10                   : 0 (unused, must be 0)
 Bit11                   : 0 (unused, must be 0)
 Bit12                   : 0 (unused, must be 0)
 Bit13                   : 0 (unused, must be 0)
 Bit14                   : 0 (unused, must be 0)
 Bit15                   : 0 (unused, must be 0)
*!*ERROR  Descriptor too short: PortPwrCtrlMask needs 1 byte to hold 8 bits
Data (HexDump)           : 09 29 08 00 00 02 00 00 00                        .).......
HubIsBusPowered          : 0x00 (Self Powered)

      ---------------- Extended USB Hub Descriptor ---------------
HubType                  : 0x01 (UsbRootHub - a root hub)
HighestPortNumber        : 0x08 (8 Ports)

        ----------------- USB Hub Capabilities ----------------
HubIs2xCapable           : 0 (Is not 2.x capable)
Data (HexDump)           : 00 00 00 00                                       ....

        --------------- USB Hub Capabilities Ex ---------------
HighSpeedCapable         : 0 (No)
HighSpeed                : 1 (Yes)
MultiTtCapable           : 0 (No)
HubIsMultiTt             : 0 (No)
ArmedWakeOnConnect       : 0 (No)
IsBusPowered             : 0 (No)
IsRoot                   : 1 (Yes)
Data (HexDump)           : 12 00 00 00                                       ....
```

```
=========================== USB Port1 ===========================

Connection Status        : 0x00 (No device is connected)
Port Chain               : 6-1
Properties               : 0x01
 IsUserConnectable       : yes
 PortIsDebugCapable      : no
 PortHasMultiCompanions  : no
 PortConnectorIsTypeC    : no
ConnectionIndex          : 0x01 (Port 1)
CompanionIndex           : 0
 CompanionHubSymLnk      : USB#ROOT_HUB30#4&a3f7854&0&0#{f18a0e88-c30c-11d0-8815-00a0c906bed8}
 CompanionPortNumber     : 0x05 (Port 5)
 -> CompanionPortChain   : 6-5

SupportedUsbProtocols    : 0x03
 Usb110                  : 1 (yes, port supports USB 1.1)
 Usb200                  : 1 (yes, port supports USB 2.0)
 Usb300                  : 0 (no, port not supports USB 3.0) -> but Companion Port 6-5 does
 ReservedMBZ             : 0x00
```

```
 =========================== USB Port2 ===========================

Connection Status        : 0x00 (No device is connected)
Port Chain               : 6-2
Properties               : 0x01
 IsUserConnectable       : yes
 PortIsDebugCapable      : no
 PortHasMultiCompanions  : no
 PortConnectorIsTypeC    : no
ConnectionIndex          : 0x02 (Port 2)
CompanionIndex           : 0
 CompanionHubSymLnk      : USB#ROOT_HUB30#4&a3f7854&0&0#{f18a0e88-c30c-11d0-8815-00a0c906bed8}
 CompanionPortNumber     : 0x06 (Port 6)
 -> CompanionPortChain   : 6-6

SupportedUsbProtocols    : 0x03
 Usb110                  : 1 (yes, port supports USB 1.1)
 Usb200                  : 1 (yes, port supports USB 2.0)
 Usb300                  : 0 (no, port not supports USB 3.0) -> but Companion Port 6-6 does
 ReservedMBZ             : 0x00
```

Comment: Thank you for providing so much information. But you should provide information about your source, your target and the connection between.

Comment: @r2d3 I am using an external SSD, the files are on my PC, and I defragged the HDDs. Using the same files and SSD just connected to a port on the back of the PC, it does not get hung up at all.

Comment: I am still missing a satisfying answer to my question. If google described a route like you do I would never find my way, sorry.

Comment: @r2d3 sorry if im being stupid, what do you need?

Comment: How is the external SSD connected to the computer? How are the HDDs connected to the computer? What is the route like? How is the second connection route different from the first one?